DataGrid. How change background color of header?
I need to change this white background Image Ref
<DataGrid
    rows={users}
    columns={columns}
    disableColumnMenu={true}
    hideFooter={true}
    loading={isLoading}
    autoHeight={true}
    sx={{
      boxShadow: 2,
      border: 2,
      borderColor: "#292524",
      "& .MuiDataGrid-cell": {
        color: "white",
        borderColor: "#292524",
      },
      "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader": {
        backgroundColor: "#0c0a09",
        color: "#75706c",
      }
    }}
/>

& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader changes the color, but only of inner header cells

The DOM hierarchy is:
<div class="MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders">
   <div role="row" class="..."> <!-- this is where actual background is set -->
      <div class="MuiDataGrid-columnHeader">
      <div class="MuiDataGrid-columnHeader">
      <div class="MuiDataGrid-columnHeader">
      <div class="MuiDataGrid-filler">
      <div class="MuiDataGrid-scrollbarFiller">
   </div>
</div>

You must change the background of the <div role="row" inside the MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders to change the background of the whole header row area.
& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders div[role="row"] {
   background-color: #0c0a09;
}

Otherwise, you must change the background of MuiDataGrid-filler class along with your previous code. (Not Recommended)
& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader,
& .MuiDataGrid-filler {
    background-color: #0c0a09;
}


mui consider blank space as a filler not as a column header, so You need to change color of MuiDataGrid-filler class also
below example will help you to achieve that
 <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        disableColumnMenu={true}
        hideFooter={true}
        loading={false}
        autoHeight={true}
        sx={{
          boxShadow: 2,
          border: 2,
          borderColor: '#292524',
          '& .MuiDataGrid-cell': {
            color: 'gray',
            borderColor: '#292524',
          },
          '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeader': {
            backgroundColor: '#0c0a09',
            color: '#75706c',
            borderBottom: '0 !important',
          },
          '& .MuiDataGrid-filler': {
            backgroundColor: '#0c0a09',
            color: '#75706c',
          },
          '& .MuiDataGrid-scrollbarFiller': {
            borderBottom: '0 !important',
          },
        }}
      />


I was able to fix the right part, but how do I repaint the bottom border? It's still the same white

Can you please provide screenshot or any other reference for more details?

https://postimg.cc/y37dQsX9
